# PHP - How do i remove last comma from the loop

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code

```
$product = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $prod = $row["prod"];
}
$product = $product. $prod. "  ,  ";
```

And the output looks something like this "chocolate,Cake," in case of multiple product while in case of single product it looks "Cake,"

I just want to remove last comma from the string

so any kind of help for this would be appreciated

Comment: use trim() function for this

Comment: Use an array and http://php.net/join - also, that code certainly does not produce that output.

Comment: @Khushboo why not `rtrim()`?

Comment: @t3chguy :- that can be used. I was just giving him direction :)

Comment: In my head I planned to put a winky face, must have forgot; was meaning my comment to add to your direction xP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$product = rtrim($product,',');
```

see [rtrim doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)